# Marquee Tool not working since trying to port to MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a marquee tool I created where it is a rectangle that you can drag across the screen, so click mouse and drag creates a marquee-tool like box.

Problem is, i've ported this to MVVM and it's just not working, my previous XAML was just a canvas inside a grid, and I was doing `Canvas.SetLeft(nameOfMyCanvas, mousePosX);`.

Now i've created a class for it and added it to the itemsource that I've created for my canvas... problem is when i click and drag, i don't see anything even though the properties for the Rect class i made are all changing correctly and accordingly.

XAML for my grid

```
<Grid Name="mainGrid" DockPanel.Dock="Left" MouseDown="MainGrid_MouseDown" MouseUp="MainGrid_MouseUp" MouseMove="MainGrid_MouseMove" Background="Transparent" 
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                  MinWidth="{Binding GridWidth}" Height="{Binding GridHeight}">
                                <ItemsControl x:Name="ObjItemControl" ItemsSource="{Binding ObjCompositeCollection}">
                                    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                                        <Style>
                                            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding Row}"/>
                                            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding Column}"/>
                                        </Style>
                                    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                            <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                             VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Name="objGrid" Grid.Row="1" 
                                             Width="{Binding MinWidth, ElementName=mainGrid}" 
                                             Height="{Binding Height, ElementName=mainGrid}"
                                             engine:GridHelper.RowCount="{Binding RowCount}"
                                             engine:GridHelper.ColumnCount="{Binding ColumnCount}" />
                                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsControl.Resources>
                                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type engine:ObjA}">
                                            <ToggleButton Content="{Binding Id}"
                                                    Tag="{Binding Id}"
                                                    IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}"
                                                    Height="{Binding ElementName=ObjItemControl, 
                                                Path=DataContext.ButtonHeightWidth}"
                                                    Width="{Binding ElementName=ObjItemControl, 
                                                Path=DataContext.ButtonHeightWidth}"
                                                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                                    Margin="{Binding ElementName=wellPlateItemControl, 
                                                Path=DataContext.ButtonMarginToUse}"
                                                    Padding="2"
                                                    PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="Button_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"
                                                    PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="Button_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp"
                                                    MouseEnter="Button_MouseEnter"
                                                    MouseLeave="Button_MouseLeave"
                                                    Style="{StaticResource ObjButton}">
                                            </ToggleButton>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type engine:GridLabeller}">
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding HeaderName}" Style="{StaticResource GridHeaders}"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ItemsControl.Resources>
                                </ItemsControl>
                                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding RectForMarquee}">
                                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                            <Canvas/>
                                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                                        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                                            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}"/>
                                            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}"/>
                                        </Style>
                                    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <Rectangle Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}"
                                                       Visibility="{Binding Visibility}" 
                                                       Stroke="{StaticResource ResourceKey=SecondaryThemeColour}" 
                                                       StrokeThickness="2" StrokeDashArray="2,1"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl>
                                <!--<Canvas>
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="selectionBox" Visibility="Collapsed" Stroke="{StaticResource ResourceKey=SecondaryThemeColour}" StrokeThickness="2" StrokeDashArray="2,1"/>
                                </Canvas>-->
                            </Grid>
```

And the code behind in the VM

```
    private RectForMarqueeTool rectForMarquee = new RectForMarqueeTool();
    public RectForMarqueeTool RectForMarquee
    {
        get { return rectForMarquee; }
        set
        {
            rectForMarquee = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(RectForMarquee));
        }
    }

    private int mainMouseX;
    public int MainGridMouseX
    {
        get { return mainMouseX; }
        set
        {
            mainMouseX = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MainGridMouseX));
        }
    }

    private int mainMouseY;
    public int MainGridMouseY
    {
        get { return mainMouseY; }
        set
        {
            mainMouseY = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MainGridMouseY));
        }
    }
```

It's usage

```
    public void MainGrid_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.UIElement source = (System.Windows.UIElement)e.Source;

        // Capture and track the mouse.
        isMouseDown = true;
        mouseDownPos = e.GetPosition(source);
        source.CaptureMouse();

        // Initial placement of the drag selection box.         
        RectForMarquee.X = mouseDownPos.X;
        RectForMarquee.Y = mouseDownPos.Y;
        RectForMarquee.Width = 0;
        RectForMarquee.Height = 0;

        // Make the drag selection box visible.
        RectForMarquee.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
```

And the RectForMarquee class itself

```
using System.Windows;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace UIChemicalMelt 
{
public sealed class RectForMarqueeTool : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private static RectForMarqueeTool instance = null;

    public RectForMarqueeTool() { }

    public static RectForMarqueeTool Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = new RectForMarqueeTool();
            }

            return instance;
        }
    }

    private double x;
    public double X
    {
        get { return x; }
        set {
            x = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private double y;
    public double Y
    {
        get { return y; }
        set
        {
            y = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private double width;
    public double Width
    {
        get { return width; }
        set
        {
            width = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private double height;
    public double Height
    {
        get { return height; }
        set
        {
            height = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private Visibility visibility;
    public Visibility Visibility
    {
        get { return visibility; }
        set
        {
            visibility = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

}

**UPDATE**

I have added the rest of my code - still, the marquee tool/rectangle is not displaying when I am dragging my mouse across the screen. Still do not know why as the RectForMarquee values are changing correctly but the UI is not updating

```
    public void MainGrid_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.UIElement source = (System.Windows.UIElement)e.Source;
        if (isMouseDown)
        {
            // When the mouse is held down, reposition the drag selection box.
            Point mousePos = e.GetPosition(source);

            SetSelectionBoxWidth(mousePos);
            SetSelectionBoxHeight(mousePos);
        }
    }

    private void SetSelectionBoxWidth(Point mousePos)
    {
        if (mouseDownPos.X < mousePos.X)
        {
            RectForMarquee.X = mouseDownPos.X;
            RectForMarquee.Width = mousePos.X - mouseDownPos.X;
        }
        else
        {
            RectForMarquee.X = mousePos.X;
            RectForMarquee.Width = mouseDownPos.X - mousePos.X;
        }

        mouseUpPos.X = mousePos.X;
    }

    private void SetSelectionBoxHeight(Point mousePos)
    {
        if (mouseDownPos.Y < mousePos.Y)
        {
            RectForMarquee.Y = mouseDownPos.Y;
            RectForMarquee.Height = mousePos.Y - mouseDownPos.Y;
        }
        else
        {
            RectForMarquee.Y = mousePos.Y;
            RectForMarquee.Height = mouseDownPos.Y - mousePos.Y;
        }

        mouseUpPos.Y = mousePos.Y;
    }
```

Comment: Why should there be a view model at all? Such a tool should be a control (e.g. a UserControl) which exposes a set of bindable properties. It shouldn't have anything like an own view model.

Comment: Would the XAML change?

Comment: If it's the XAML of a UserControl, the UI elements would typically bind to the properties exposed by the control via Bindings with `RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}`.

Comment: but I mean the general layout. Like, at the moment do you know why it would not be working? It originally was a UserControl (if you noticed the commented out part of the XAML and I was calling it directly in the UserControl I made for it)

Comment: I'll keep that in mind about using the `RelativeSource` attribute for the usercontrol, but is there any way I can get it working as it is? I'll change it once I get it working - I just didn't think it would not be working tbh

Comment: Any idea Clemens? Or anyone else?

Comment: @Clemens do you know where I could go to ask and see if anyone knows what wrong?